# Fetching a specific SQL column's content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table containing columns for user IP (IP) and their name (Name). I want to compare the user's browser IP to the IP column the SQL table, and save their name to a PHP variable $name should an IP match be found.

I'm using `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to save the browser's IP. How would I go about comparing this variable to the IP addresses in the SQL database? I tried `$getname = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM MyTable WHERE IP=$ip");` but this seems to return a Resource ID.

My apologizes if the question seems awfully elementary; I'm rather new to SQL (and PHP, for that matter). Also, I'm not in need for a secure way of authenticating for this one.

Comment: can you tell us more about the problem and what's happening then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code, after firing the query you have to iterate the result to get the output.

```
 $getname = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM MyTable WHERE IP='$ip'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($getname)>0)
 {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getname))
      {
           echo $row['Name'];
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Seems that I also didn't wrap my $ip in quotes properly.

Comment: @user2082033 Accept the answer if it is useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the value of `IP` with single quote.

```
mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM MyTable WHERE IP='$ip'");
```